# Why is this happening? Think it is an issue with clearfix?

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

Here is the issue: As you can see on the left the floated elements do not align, and on the right they do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx8Zs.jpg

This doesn't happen all the time, and it isn't browser specific (AFAIK) - it corrects itself upon refresh... I'm thinking it's a problem with the clearfix? CSS below.

```
.clear:after {
    clear: both; 
    content: "."; 
    display: block; 
    font-size:0;
    height: 0; 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.clear { 
    display: inline-block;  
}
* html .clear {  
    height: 1%;  
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clear {  
    display: block;  
}
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ demo?

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you've posted but a guess would be some sort of width issue. If you can post a jsfiddle or a link to your webpage that would help.

Comment: I need to look the html div hierarchy?
Some times you have to specify the width of the container. And, why are you clearing so much? Usually you clear when you have floating boxes somewhere on top.

Comment: link to the webpage is http://www.mckiewebdesign.co.uk/melonbrew/

Comment: the only affected elements seem to be the nav and footer as far as i can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem but here's some suggestions.

1. Give you #networks div a width
2. Give #networks overflow:auto
3. Remove the clear div from #networks
4. Include the HTML5 shive for IE if you haven't already (I couldn't see it)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer http://jsfiddle.net/xVzAY/

Comment: It's fine to link to services like JSFiddle with SO, but please also post your code directly into your answer. Also, you should explain *why* this code is the answer.

Comment: Please check this link. [How to answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)